# Execute bash script from groovy in linux

Tags: linux, groovy, echo

I have a bash script on my server which fetches master branch from github, builds it and deploys artifacts to the tomcat. I decided to write a github web URL hook which will call this sh. As my server is running Java, I'm using groovy. I writed a test script `test.sh` in `/home/madhead/scripts`:

```
echo "SHELL"
touch /home/madhead/test_`date +%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S` # To see if script is actually called
```

Environment variable `SCRIPTS` is set to `/home/madhead/scripts` in `/home/madhead/.bashrc`. In my groovlet I have

```
println "GROOVY"
println '$SCRIPTS/test.sh'.execute().text
println `whoami'.execute().text` //Prints madhead
println `env'.execute().text` //Prints all environment variables for madhead, SHELL is /bin/bash and SCRIPTS is /home/madhead/scripts in this output.
```

"GROOVY" is printend in html, but no "SHELL" and no test files are created when i calling groovlet. So, the script is not called. I tried

```
println '/home/madhead/scripts/test.sh'.execute().text
```

in groovlet with no effect. How do i call bash script from groovy/java? Also, `println 'echo test'.execute().text` prints test to html, but `println 'echo $SCRIPTS'.execute().text` does not print anything. Why?

Comment: did you try adding a shebang to the script?

Comment: You are rigth, there were no shebang in shell script. But when i added it nothing changed.

Comment: UPD. Also, it ocurred that i need to call waitFor() on process. When i don't do this shell script is not not executing.

Comment: Are you sure that your shell script is executable? `chmod +x test.sh`

Comment: Sure, it is execuable, i can call it from shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe to get the environment variable you need to:

```
def env = System.getenv()
println env.SCRIPTS
```

In my box this guy works:

```
groovy -e ' def env = System.getenv(); println env.JAVA_HOME '
```

Comment: There is no SCRIPTS variable in System.getenv(). I've added the shebang to the shell script and calling it by absolute path.

Comment: Yes, i understood the issue, i wrote #!/bin/sh, while setting SCRIPTS in bash config. Now i call the shell script with def p = "${System.getenv().SCRIPTS}/test.sh".execute(); p.waitFor(); println p.text